# Sorting array of string arrays

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, sorting

I am sending a ArrayList as below from a web service call :

private ArrayList testList = new ArrayList();

Which will store values like :

```
"xyz (pound) (4545)"
"abc (in)    (346)"
"def (off)   (42424)"
```

I use this because of two reasons :

**1 : I have to fetch this value in ASP.NET 1.1 framework.**

**2 : I use testList.Sort(); before sending.**

But now I want to send these values as :

```
"xyz"   "pound"  "4545"
"abc"  "in"    "346"
"def"   "off" "42424"
```

So I found a way as below :

```
string[][] data = { new string[]{"xyz", "pound", "4545"},
                    new string[]{"abc", "in", "346"}, 
                    new string[]{"def", "off", "42424"}};
```

**Question is : How can I sort it effectively?? OR Is there a better way to address this ?**

Sort will be done based on first element :

```
abc
def
xyz
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You write that you have to *read* this value in ASP 1.1, so I assume that you have a more modern version of the .NET framework available on the *sending* side.

If that is the case, you can use the [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) method of LINQ, included in Framework 3.5 or higher:

```
string[][] data = { new string[] { "xyz", "pound", "4545" }, 
                    new string[] { "abc", "in", "346" }, 
                    new string[] { "def", "off", "42424" } };
data = data.OrderBy(entry => entry[0]).ToArray();  // sorts by first field
```

Comment: Just wonder how this solution differs from my? Also comment it is wrong, because sorting is done by array item, not by field

Comment: Off the question -- I am adding these string arrays in loop...like this `//Adding each information to the array of string.
                        data = new string[3];
                        data[0] = "xyz";
                        data[1] = "8787";
                        data[2] = "dad";

                        //Adding each row to the array list.
                        arrList.Add(data);//Adding array list to the property object.
                        vinDescription.ShowOptionalEquipment = (string[][])arrList.ToArray(typeof(string[]));` ... Is this correct or a better way is there??

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: It doesn't differ significantly, we just happened to come up with the same solution at the same time. I used the term `field` in an informal sense here (call it an analogy or metaphor), since the inner array seems to represent some kind of *record*.

Comment: @Learner: I don't see a problem with your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just sort inner arrays by first item in array

```
string[][] sorted = data.OrderBy(array => array[0]).ToArray();
```

Comment: What will be the type of **sorted** ??

Comment: Array of string arrays, or `string[][]`. I used `var` just for shortening

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer is correct only in case we are trying to compare first letter of the string. I had similiar issue and to get accurate sorting, you need to order by whole string not just first char.

`data = data.OrderBy(entry => entry).ToArray();  // sorts by first field`